# replace all instances of string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Simple question here.

I need to replace all instances of a string in the URL with another string.

IE. I need to replace every instance of "test" in the URL, with .htaccess code.

For example "www.example.com/test/A/test/B/test" will become "www.example.com/REP/A/REP/B/REP".

I can produce a script that replaces "test" with "REP", when "test" is not at the end or the beginning of the script. But I cannot come up with a final script to replace "test" everywhere.

My code:

```
RewriteRule ^test\/(.*) REP/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, that is all knowing and beatiful.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)test(.*)$ $1FIN$2 [R=301,L]
```